# How to edit/download '*.cshtml' and other Asp.Net files via WebDav on IIS 7.x

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5, webdav

I have installed WebDav on Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition and the connection is working perfectly except when I try to download a *protected* Asp.Net file, like `myfile.cshtml` or `web.config` I get an `Error downloading file! (404)`.

All the other files work fine.

I guess some ISAPI is blocking the access somehow. I found this article but it didn't solve my problem: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/hosting_iis_asp_net/protected_folders

I removed the `RequestFilteringModule`, every `aspnet_filter.dll`, every entry for `Request Filtering`. I can see my `App_Data` folder. I can upload `*.cshtml` files and delete them. I can even overwrite them but I can't download them.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt that does most of what you want (allowing .config, .cs, and ect.):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <clear />
        </fileExtensions>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <clear />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove path="*" verb="GET" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I'm still working on the .cshtml bit...

**EDIT:** I have updated this with what is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following section in **Views/web.config**

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Removing the BlockViewHandler didn't help.